# Evalulate $\iint_{D}^{} (x+y) dx dy$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Let $D$ be the region $0 \leq y \leq x$ and $0 \leq x \leq 1$. Evalulate $\iint_{D}^{} (x+y) dx dy$ by making the change of variables $x = u + v$ and $y = u - v$.

($D$ here is the image set, so we need to find the limits for the pre-image in order to evaluate the integral.)

I know how to make the substitution and find the Jacobian determinant, but I'm having trouble figuring out the limits for the pre-image of the transformation.

1) I am unsure what $0 \leq y \leq x$ means. I plugged in several points for $x$ and $y$ in this inequality, and the image looks like it is a triangle, I think. But I don't know how to prove it for sure that it's a triangle.

2) I believe the parametrization for the transformation of the image to the pre-image, based on the assumption that the image is a triangle, is:

$$f_1 = (t, 0), t \in [0,1] \\
f_1 = (1, t) t \in [0,1]\\
f_1 = (t, t) t \in [0,1]
$$

In order to obtain the transformation from the pre-image to the image, I need to find the inverses of these parametrizations but I don't know how.

Comment: $0\leq y\leq x$ is really a combination of $0\leq y$ and $y\leq x$; shade in those two regions (using different styles) and then shade in $0\leq x\leq 1$ in the same manner, using two other different styles - you'll see that your guess is correct and that this is indeed a triangle-shaped region ($0\leq y$ and $0\leq x$ tell you you're restricted to Q1, $y\leq x$ tells you you're below the line $y=x$ and $x\leq1$ tells you you're to the left of $x=1$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in identifying the fact that the change-of-variables transformation maps a subset $C$ of the $(u, v)$-plane diffeomorphically onto the subset $D$ of the $(x, y)$-plane.  The map is
$$
\phi(u, v) = (u + v, u - v),
$$
so
$$
\left\{ \begin{align}
x = u + v \\
y = u - v
\end{align} \right.
$$
Since
$$
\iint_D F(x, y) \, dx \, dy = \iint_C F( \phi(u, v) ) \, |J_{\phi}(u, v)| \, du \, dv,
$$
we need to describe the preimage $C = \phi^{-1}(D)$.  It is defined by the inequalities
$$
\left\{ \begin{align}
0 \le &u + v \le 1 \\
0 \le &u - v \le u + v
\end{align} \right.
$$
The second inequality gives the fact that $0 \le v \le u$, while the first gives $-u \le v \le 1 - u$.  Together, these inequalities imply that
$$
\left\{ \begin{align}
v \le &u \le 1 - v \\
0 \le &v \le \tfrac{1}{2}
\end{align} \right.
$$
Now,
$$
J_{\phi}(u, v) = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
with determinant $-2$.  Finally, the integrand is
$$
F(\phi(u, v)) = 2u.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\iint_D \left( x + y \right) \, dx \, dy &= \iint_C \left( 2u \right ) (-2) \, du \, dv \\
&= \int_0^{\tfrac{1}{2}} \int_v^{1-v} -4u \, du \, dv.
\end{align}
$$

I will leave it there.

Answer (score 0):

The region $D$ is $x \in [0,1]$ and $y \in [0,x]$ (a triangle) so this means

$$ \iint_D (x+ y)dy dx =  \int_0^1 \left (\int_0^x (x+y)dy \right ) dx =\int_0^1 \left (x^2+ \frac{x^2}{2} \right) dx  = \frac{1}{2}$$

Thought I'd include the straight forward computation aswell